# is there any alternative OS to give more lifetime to an older iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an old iPad that was stranded in my possessions a while ago. It has iOS 9.xx installed and won't update any longer. Also more and more Apps are stopping to work because the newer version won't run on 9.x OS anymore.

Considering the state of the planet on the whole it would be nice to being able to install any sort of alternative OS to such a technological masterpiece in nearly mint condition and likewise give it a few more years of being useful.

Can anyone advise whether there is any project that would be worth looking at in this regards?

Comment: You may consider looking into [iOS Jailbreaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking).

Comment: Various groups are working on it. You can keep up with the state of things on this site: https://ipadlinux.org/ I don't know if any of those projects are usable yet.

Comment: tx, I'll check that out

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know: Not really.

The best you can do is to jailbreak it and nope people have archived / cracked old versions of apps that either entertain you or still work as @Nimesh Neema suggested.

For current hardware and software, jailbreaks can add new features and light customization of iOS, it’s not really a new OS. Almost never does a jailbreak allow you to install apps that require a newer iOS, but likely you can install apps outside of the AppStore or ones that are no longer signed or updated or distributed from Apple.

I am pretty sure though, what you are looking for, does not exist.