# iPad 2 in the year 2022

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation, ipados

I own an iPad 2 (MC980/A) with 32 GB of storage in good condition. It has no scratches nor cracks. It runs iOS 9 as the latest software. [Any suggestions about things I could do with my iPad 2 are very much appreciated.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379864/)

Can I get newer third party applications, operating system or other software for this iPad?

Answer (score 5):

The iPad 2 was released with iOS 4.3 and you're now running iOS 9.3.6 as the latest. Given that the product was launched in 2011 discontinued in 2014 and received as recently as July 2019, you will have received somewhere from 8.5 to 5.5 years of first party software updates. This is considerably more than the industry standard. I doubt that Apple will ever make new releases for this iPad in terms of the operating system and their built-in apps.

Remember that Apple has not stopped you from using the product, they have not disabled your operating system and they have not removed your installed apps. It still runs iOS 9 and the app it had installed. You are simply not receiving new software update from Apple anymore.

The main problem with old operating systems on any device is security when connected to a network. It is simply not wise to connect such a device to the Internet for example - unless you do not care that you risk getting malware, virusses, etc. It is not something Apple has dictated - that goes for any device from any vendor running any kind of operating system. You could argue that Apple should keep making updates for their devices until the last sold product breaks beyond repair. This is not really reasonable though, as the costs of producing such updates are much, much higher than most realize.

You can however download new software from the App Store that third party app developers have made available for older versions of the iPad.

Many third party app developers unfortunately do not support older iPads for that many years. Apps such as for example Instagram are not isolated islands - they require a set of servers in the cloud to talk to. Instagram could decide to keep supporting their old apps indefinitely, but they have chosen not to - so at some point, their app stopped working - and they withdraw it from the App Store for those, now unsupported devices.

You can also install third party software from outside the App Store. You can do that by compiling and signing apps yourself and addding them to the iPad (the signing has to be redone periodically).

Another option is to jailbreak the device to install software from any third party. There's many jailbreak tools out there for the iPad 2. You do not need to connect the iPad to a computer to install the jailbreak.

Note that after jail breaking, you'll find that most third-party app stores have also stopped supporting these old iPads. It's not just a big burden for Apple to support old devices, it is also so for third parties.

If you're looking for new stuff to do with your old iPad, there's plenty of projects and ideas that you could start on. An old iPad could be used for example as wall-mounted remote for a music system, it could be used as an alarm clock on your nightstand, it could be used a digital photo frame, it could be mounted in your kitchen solely for easy access to recipes, etc. Plenty of stuff you can actually do with an old iPad.

There's also the option of gifting the iPad (for example donating it to a charitable organisation). If you find no use for it at all, and do not want to gift or sell it, make sure your recycle the device. You can often hand the old iPad in at any Apple Store for recycling - depending on which country, you reside in. For more details look [here](https://www.apple.com/recycling/nationalservices/).

Answer (score 2):

[As this question on alternative OS for iPad explains](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/379867/5472), no viable third party OS option exists today yet jailbreaking might help with side loading old non-Apple store apps.  Be careful since you’re now a bit more responsible for watching for malware and bugs, but those risks can be managed with education and network monitoring.

- No new os
- No new apps
- Some ability to side load old apps
- Some chances you could write custom apps using old development tools

As long as the hardware is sound, the device will continue working as it is, and you can continue to use it in the way that you have always done. I'd suggest that the device will serve as a general media viewer/player: PDFs, ebooks, music (perhaps not videos with only 32Gb); also for taking notes.

However, you are right that as time goes by, the browser becomes less capable in rendering modern websites; it also will have vulnerabilities that won't get patched. You won't be able to download new apps, because those apps rely on newer OS versions.

Applications are (very crudely) instructions for the Operating System to follow. Each new OS contains new instructions. New versions of applications might use the new instructions, and older OSes can't understand those apps.

There comes a point when the cost to Apple of continuing to support older devices outweighs the number of such devices still in use. You can argue that Apple ought to do more to allow or help with jail-breaking and running some other OS on older devices; though doing so might have security implications for newer devices.

"To everything there is a season, and a time for every purpose under heaven: a time to keep, and a time to throw away."

Comment: Forgive the opinions at the top - I wanted to harmonize this with the related question so they don’t immediately end up as duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use it as a secondary monitor. You have to use a Mac companion app to connect to the iPad. There are multiple solutions, I found Yam Display useful because it supports my iPad 2. You can use your iPad as a monitor on wifi or with USB. There is a time-limited free version you can try.